# Adicionar Objeto em uma Lista com C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Meus objetos aparentemente estão sendo adicionados na minha lista, mas quando vou chamar a lista no update() ela não executa como esperado.

```
public class CenaCozinha : MonoBehaviour {

//Os Alimentos
public GameObject Alimento;
public GameObject Agua;
public GameObject Melancia;
public List<Alimentos> alimentosCozinha = new List<Alimentos>();    

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InicializarAlimentos();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    foreach (Alimentos al in alimentosCozinha) {
        if (al.nomeAlimento == "agua") {
            Agua.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log(al.nomeAlimento);
        }
        if (al.nomeAlimento == "melancia") { //ele não entra aqui
            Melancia.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log(al.nomeAlimento);
        }
    }
}

public void InicializarAlimentos() {         //aqui ele adiciona
    Alimentos novoAlimento = Alimento.AddComponent<Alimentos>();
    novoAlimento.id = "agua";
    novoAlimento.nomeAlimento = "agua";
    alimentosCozinha.Add(novoAlimento); 
}

public void ComprarAgua() {
    Alimentos novoAlimento = Alimento.AddComponent<Alimentos>();
    novoAlimento.id = "agua";
    novoAlimento.nomeAlimento = "agua";
    alimentosCozinha.Add(novoAlimento);     
}
public void ComprarMelancia() {
    Alimentos novoAlimento = Alimento.AddComponent<Alimentos>();
    novoAlimento.id = "melancia";
    novoAlimento.nomeAlimento = "melancia";
    alimentosCozinha.Add(novoAlimento);
}
} }
```

Quando, apos Add, coloco:
`Debug.Log(alimentosCozinha.Count);`
Ele mostra que aumentou a contagem.

Aguardo um retorno, ja estou a um bom tempo com esse problema...
Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc nao está adicionando Melancia a sua lista, por isso jamais o segundo If do Update será verdadeiro.
Tem mais alguns erros de lógica no seu script, que sinto muito, não tive como debbugar por estar sem unity, e de cabeça estou sujeito a erros. Então para não falar merda, só vou apontar o que vi do problema de log.

A função InicializarAlimento só adiciona água, e não encontrei em mais lugar algum a chamada para as funções de compra... portanto não é adicionado mais nada além de água na sua lista... Tenta substituir sua inicialização por algo do tipo:

```
public void InicializarAlimentos() {
    ComprarAgua();
    ComprarMelancia();
}
```

Coloca um Debug.log() no update, e chama essas funções pra ver se funcionam... Se nao funcionar, tem mais uns erros ai relacionados a essa criação de objeto da lista..

Boa sorte aew.

Comment: Estou chamando ComprarMelancia(); ao clicar em um botão no Unity; No caso o game ja inicia com Agua adicionado na lista (que é o que ocorre no InicializarAlimentos();) Mas, ao clicar em ComprarMelancia, ele aparentemente nao adiciona... mesmo o 'Debug.Log(alimentosCozinha.Count);' mostrando que aumentou a contagem.

Ps: Quando chamo a função ComprarMelancia() direto no Update, ele adiciona normal e entra no if.

Comment: Consegui, eu estava colocando um Objeto diferente no unity. O código esta correto, o problema era no Unity. Valeu ;D

Comment: Boa.. Então, como não via onde era chamado a ComprarMelancia não tinha muito como ajudar haha.. Mas que bom que deu certo haha.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso!

```
public class CenaCozinha : MonoBehaviour {

   //Os Alimentos
   public GameObject Alimento;
   public GameObject Agua;
   public GameObject Melancia;
   public List<Alimentos> alimentosCozinha;    

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
     alimentosCozinha = new List<Alimentos>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

     foreach (Alimentos al in alimentosCozinha) {
        if (al.nomeAlimento == "agua") {
           Agua.SetActive(true);
           Debug.Log(al.nomeAlimento);
        }
        else if (al.nomeAlimento == "melancia") {
           Melancia.SetActive(true);
           Debug.Log(al.nomeAlimento);
        }
     }
  }

  public void ComprarAgua() {
     Alimentos novoAlimento = Alimento.AddComponent<Alimentos>();
     novoAlimento.id = "agua";
     novoAlimento.nomeAlimento = "agua";
     alimentosCozinha.Add(novoAlimento);     
  }

  public void ComprarMelancia() {
     Alimentos novoAlimento = Alimento.AddComponent<Alimentos>();
     novoAlimento.id = "melancia";
     novoAlimento.nomeAlimento = "melancia";
     alimentosCozinha.Add(novoAlimento);
  }
}
```

Ou se preferir usar `InicializarAlimentos()`...

```
public void InicializarAlimentos() {
   alimentosCozinha = new List<Alimentos>();
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente o 'erro' continua...